# Primefaces p:fileupload get all the pictures

Tags: java, primefaces, ejb

I wanna know how could I get all the pictures from a `P:FILEUPLOAD` in only one event upload.

1.-

```xml
<p:fileUpload 
    mode="advanced" 
    update="messages" 
    fileLimit="10" 
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" 
    sequential="true" 
    process="@this" 
    fileUploadListener="#{publicacionesController.handleFileUpload}"/>
```

2.-

```java
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    System.out.println("El size lista1: " + imgs.size());
    imgs.add(event.getFile());
    System.out.println("El size lista2: " + imgs.size());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

I need load the 10 in my list "imgs" but the every picture load in a diferent event and when I try to use my list only has one picture (the last in the event).

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna know how could I get all the pictures from a `P:FILEUPLOAD` in **only one event** upload.

As stated in [PrimeFaces Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#page=213&zoom=auto,56.7,773.3), this is not possible:

> **Multiple Uploads**
>
> ... Note that multiple 
>   mode is for selection only, it does not send all files in one request. FileUpload component always uses a  new request for each file.